# Why is the Row Sampling transformation in SSIS blocking?

Tags: ssis

According to the Microsoft Training Kit 70-463 and most online sources, Row Sampling in SSIS is a blocking transformation. Why is it blocking? It seems unnecessary for the whole data set to be blocked if you are just randomly choosing a fixed number of rows. It is especially strange since Percent Sampling is non-blocking. Does anybody have an explanation for this behavior? Or evidence that it is not blocking, as claimed in [this blog post](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/Daniel/ssas/1361/ssis-blocking-non-blocking-and-partially-blocking-transformations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percent sample transformation takes the same percentage of each buffer. It knows in advance, how much rows to take from each buffer (based on the size of the buffer), so it can process a buffer immediately and let it fly down the pipeline.
Row sample transformation, on the other hand, doesn't know in advance, how much rows does it need from each buffer, because it doesn't know how much buffers it is waiting for. So this transformation has to wait, count all the buffers, then calculate, how much rows to take from each buffer, and then process all those buffers.
Proof (based on SSIS logging): http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2014/06/is-row-sampling-transformation-fully.html